# A server-side hook failed when committing plugin code to SVN

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, svn

We're trying to commit and push our initial release to the SVN repository assigned to us by the wordpress team.

However when committing the code we're getting an error (probably because of the PHP8 polyfill) but are a bit baffled why this is stopping the plugin from being deployed?

In the readme.txt and composer we specifically also set the min. version of PHP to 7.0

[image]

Comment: This is something you'll need to discuss with the WordPress.org team. You should be able to get assistance in their Slack. No one here's going to be able to be much help, especially since the code in question does not appear to even be code you've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing this with the WP plugin review team.

The precommit hook that is being run on the server does not yet support PHP8.
Removing any dependencies on the PHP80 polyfill code in vendor packages should fix this until they upgrade the precommit hooks to support PHP8.

> Just noting on the discussion above related to symfony/polyfill-mbstring the Symfony polyfills now include files which are only PHP8-syntax, but those files are only included on PHP8, the PHP7 variant is included for the rest of the users.
> Same situation as when the libraries added PHP 7.3/7.4 syntax and we were strictly requiring 7.0 or something.

> Using the older version of the library is the proper solution for now.
> The SVN server will lint with PHP8 once it’s deployed for usage on WordPress.org web requests, which while it has no timeline, I expect it’s probably going to happen at some point in the next few months, but before it’s widespread adoption.